# Create expandable HTML from markdown

Tags: markdown

We are creating "secure coding guidelines".

We face this problem: If we don't add explanations and examples the rules will be to dry.

If we add explanations and examples, then the text might get too long.

I see three solutions:

- v1: We create a table with three columns (rule, explanation, examples). But this makes no fun to edit.
- v2: We use one source file and create two HTML versions: One with explanations and examples, one without them.
- v3: We create an interactive HTML where you can expand/collapse the explanations and examples.

How to do v2 or v3  with markdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with pure Markdown but you can use HTML (summary tag).

Please check [the following tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_summary.asp) for more details.

Comment: Links are great, but answers should stand on their own. What happens if this link breaks? Please include a concise example _directly in your question_. See [answer].